# mysqli_real_escape_string makes empty string

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

i have this script.

```
<?php  
session_start();
if (!isset($_POST['text']) || $_POST['text'] == "" || strlen($_POST['text']) < 5) {
echo "error";
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=../prispevky/add.php">';
return 0;}
else $text = $_POST['text'];

if (!isset ($_SESSION['nick'])) {
echo "error";
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=../error.php">';
return 0;}
else $nick = $_SESSION['nick'];

$time = time();

$farby = array("red","blue","green", "brown", "orange", "purple", "grey", "lime", "yellow", "pink");
include_once "../inkludy/conect.php";
$new = $_POST['text'];
echo $new;
$new = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['text']);
echo $new;

$new = str_replace(array("\\r\\n", "\n"), "</br>", $new);
for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
if (preg_match ('/&lt; .{1,10} &gt;/', $new, $meno)){
    $nove_meno = preg_replace('/(&lt; )|( &gt;)/', '', $meno[0]);
    $new = preg_replace('/' . $meno[0] . '/', '<b style="color:' . $farby[$i] . '">>' . $nove_meno . '<</b>', $new);
}
}

    try {
    $query = "INSERT INTO hlasky (autor,text,onoff,time) VALUES (:nick,:new,:onoff,:time)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindValue(':nick', $nick, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':new', $new, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':onoff', '1', PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(':time', $time, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();}

catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();}
?>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;url=../hmenu/najn.php">
```

$_POST = "asdasd" and

```
$new = $_POST['text'];
echo $new;
```

works right but and echos asdasd but

```
$new = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['text']);
echo $new;
```

makes $new empty. everybody thinks that i dont have mysql connection but i have and

```
INSERT INTO hlasky (autor,text,onoff,time) VALUES (:nick,:new,:onoff,:time)
```

works too but :new is empty 
can you help me how not to loose $new string ?

this is my connection script included by include_once "../inkludy/conect.php";

```
<?php
$server = "localhost";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$databaza_meno = "iz";

$dsn = "mysql:unix_socket=/tmp/mysql50.sock;dbname=$databaza_meno";
$conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);

$db_spojenie = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);
$db = mysql_select_db($databaza_meno, $db_spojenie);
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf-8");
?>
```

Comment: you should not be using *real_escape_string with PDO. oh your mixing mysql and mysqli and pdo all togeather

Comment: Why are you mixing `mysql_*` and PDO?

Comment: so i should use only PDO or real_escape_string ?

Comment: @OdkoPP You use PDO **or** mysqli, not both. Then use prepared statements and forget about escaping the strings.

Comment: so i can delete real_escape_string and use only PDO ?

Comment: @OdkoPP yes, you can do that. Try googling "pdo prepared statements tutorial" and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to remove mysqli_real_escape_string and use only PDO because prepared statements provide automagic escaping.

Answer (score -4):

I believe you need to specify a link when calling `mysqli_real_escape_string`.  I don't use PDO very often but I believe that since your link `$conn` is in PDO, you need to specify a new link using `mysqli_connect` if you want to use any function beginning with mysqli.

Documentation for `mysqli_real_escape_string` is here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: you don't use *_real_escape_string, if using PDO

Comment: But the question was about mysqli_real_escape_string, not PDO.

Comment: @SethRachwitz you use one or the other, but not both. In fact the question contains all three mysql APIs if you want to get technical.

Comment: i expected to see addslashes used for sanitation to :-)